# result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off

Tags: caching, transactions, aop, spring-annotations

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0':
> Bean with name
> 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0'
> has been injected into other beans
> [org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor] in its raw
> version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been
> wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version
> of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching -
> consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag
> turned off, for example.  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1366)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1454)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:295)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1379)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1537)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1547)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1526)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) 27 Aug, 2013 8:33:09 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE:
> Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
> class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0':
> Bean with name
> 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0'
> has been injected into other beans
> [org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor] in its raw
> version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been
> wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version
> of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching -
> consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag
> turned off, for example.  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1366)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1454)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:295)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1379)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1537)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1547)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1526)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

### my application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-lazy-init="true">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to 
        configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.voterite.service" />
    
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    
    <cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Ehcache library setup -->
    <bean id="ehcache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache/ehcache.xml" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am using `@cachable` and aop annotation
how to slove `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException`:
please help

Answer (score 20):

I added [`@Lazy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) annotation for the field in Validator class:

```
@Autowired
@Lazy
private Service service;
```

when encountered org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:

> "Error creating bean with name 'Service': Bean with name 'Service' has
>   been injected into other beans [Validator]... "
>
> "result of over-eager type matching -  consider using
>   getBeanNamesOfType  with the allowEagerInit flag turned off"

Answer (score 1):

Use `default-lazy-init="true"` in your `applicationContext.xml`, but this is only during development time.

For staging or testing build we have to remove it as it will catch all the initial bean errors.

I found an exception to be coming on my machine and not colleague's, and that is why I used it and resumed my work.

For example use at the top `beans default-lazy-init="true" xmlns= your xmlns`

Comment: by "an exception" do you mean the exception stated above? If so change "an" to "this".